# Displaying count based on several columns-- a report query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a report to display count of transactions based on user, tariff plan type of operation and status of the transaction. What is the best possible way to do this. IS multiple groupby possible and feasible?

Sample data and output:

```
Date         Plan            Total  USer   Type of operation    status product 
2/8/2017    Entel Prepago Smart 5   01234567    Venta          Success   sim
2/8/2017    Super Plan          3   01234568    Venta          Success  pack
2/8/2017    Entel Prepago Smart 1   01234567    Venta          Cancel   sim
2/8/2017    Super Plan          1   01234568    Venta          Cancel   sim
2/8/2017    Entel Prepago       2   01234567    Reposicion     Cancel   sim
2/9/2017    Entel Prepago       10  01234570    Portabilidad  Success   pack
2/9/2017    Entel Prepago Smart 1   01234567    Venta         Pending   pack
2/9/2017    Super Plan          1   01234568    Portabilidad  Success   sim
```

Comment: Yes it is feasible. Please post the sample data and expected output

Comment: @GurV: Here is the sample data and expected output: Date Plan Total USer Type of Operation status product
2/8/2017 Entel Prepago Smart 5 01234567 Venta Success sim
2/8/2017 Super Plan 3 01234568 Venta Success pack
2/8/2017 Entel Prepago Smart 1 01234567 Venta Cancel sim
2/8/2017 Super Plan 1 01234568 Venta Cancel sim
2/8/2017 Entel Prepago 2 01234567 Reposicion Cancel sim
2/9/2017 Entel Prepago 10 01234570 Portabilidad Success pack
2/9/2017 Entel Prepago Smart 1 01234567 Venta Pending pack
2/9/2017 Super Plan 1 01234568 Portabilidad Success sim

Comment: Where? [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42104002/edit) the question and provide it there.

Comment: I still don't see the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can multiple group by.

You can try this query :
`SELECT COUNT(transaction), user, tariff_plan, status FROM your_table GROUP BY user, tariff_plan, status`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
    user, plan, type_of_operation, status,
    count(*) cnt
from your_table
group by
    user, plan, type_of_operation, status;
```